# How to track if an recipient responded to an email with amazon ses or other provider

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Hey all thanks in advance for the look.

We are attempting to develop a drip campaign email platform. For each "drip"we need to detect if the recipient replied to the email.

If so we would like discontinue the following drips.

For this we need some sort of reply detection but everything I have seen about tracking email metrics online is related to bounce rate and open rate.

Not much available on reply rate in terms of how to build such functionality.

Preferably we would like to do this on Amazon SES but if there is no such option we are willing to look at other smtp providers.

Perhaps there is some unique header we can save with the outbound email, then check against all the inbox emails.  I guess this relates to how do email clients know to thread emails - perhaps it's a similar process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch/read the email replies.
For that you will have to create 'Rule Sets' within the 'Email Receiving section' of SES.
The replies can be redirected to services like S3, SNS,Lambda, workmail to name a few and then you can read those from that redirected service